# vcpkg - build a static library without integrating with VS

Tags: c++17, vcpkg, visual-studio-2019

I need to build a 3rd party library. I am thinking about using vcpkg, as the library is included in vcpkg projects.

While reading various resources regarding using the vcpkg, I could not find any information if/how I could build a static library without integrating this library into Visual Studio first.

Is it possible to do it, or do I need first to build and integrate the library with VS and only after that export the binaries into a separate library binary file?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the triplet 'x64-windows-static' ? It has static library linkage and static CRT linkage. 
I also don't what you mean by "build and integrate the library with VS"

Comment: I used it and it works. Only I was wondering if I can build libraries without vcpkg changing environment settings for Visual Studio, which are made so the VS could find the libs. I wanted to exclude the VS from the process, just to build the libs.

Comment: If you are using CMake there is no reason to run ./vcpkg integrate install if you mean that with changing the environment. 
If you don't want to use the default triplets and use e.g. mingw instead you have to use one of the community triplets like x64-mingw.